# Enable minishift/cdk metrics

Tags: openshift, minishift, redhat-containers

I am trying to configure the Container developtment Kit to support metrics.

The documentation that I have found doesn´t work.

It is possible to enable the metrics?. I am tring to configure the CDK to see the autoscaled.

Thanks.

Comment: What documentation are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

With CDK 3.4 you can try to deploy Metrics as part of `minishift start`:

`MINISHIFT_ENABLE_EXPERIMENTAL=y ./cdk-3.4.0-2-minishift-linux-amd64 start --metrics --memory 8gb`

This feature is however experimental and unfortunately not performing well in last few releases. And so it is highly possible that you will end up with broken Metrics. Due to unsatisfactory performance the Metrics feature [got removed from Minishift](https://github.com/minishift/minishift/pull/2241) recently and it could be expected that it will not be part of next CDK release.